# Read large amount of data from standard input

Tags: linux, go, buffer, stdin

How do you read lots of data from stdin in Golang? All of my reads currently stop at 4095 bytes. I've tried lots of things but my current code looks like:

```
var stdinReader = bufio.NewReader(os.stdin)

// Input reads from stdin while echoing back.
func Input(prompt string) []byte {
    var data []byte

    // Output prompt.
    fmt.Print(prompt)

    // Read until newline.
    for {
        bytes, isPrefix, _ := stdinReader.ReadLine()
        data = append(data, bytes...)

        if !isPrefix {
            break
        }
    }

    // Everything went well. Return the data.
    return data
}
```

I've also tried using a scanner but couldn't figure out how to exit

```
for scanner.Scan() {
    data = append(data, scanner.Bytes()...)
}
```

when a newline occurred (i.e. when the user pressed return).

I also tried ReadBytes('\n') but even that stopped at 4095 bytes. Short of increasing the size of the buffer (which is just an ugly hack) I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: Before addressing the question of how to read > 4095 bytes, what is the goal you are trying to achieve? Slurping "large amounts" of data into a byte array is usually a bad idea. For most use cases, you should operate on streams, for better performance, and lower memory consumption.

Comment: @Flimzy That's a good point, and I'll keep it in mind. I later plan on using files for input and so it would be in chunks (i.e. a stream). I'm just wondering if there's an idiomatic way of reading more than 4095 bytes from stdin.

Comment: Why do you use [ReadLine](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadLine)? When `stdin` has no `\n` it will stop, because you break, when isPrefix. How about using `Read()`?

Comment: @apxp Read() isn't suitable since it isn't known in advance how much data the user will input.

Answer (score 2):

If you'll look at Go sources, you will see that it uses default buffer size:

```
func NewReader(rd io.Reader) *Reader {
    return NewReaderSize(rd, defaultBufSize)
}
```

So you can use in your code as:

```
var stdinReader = bufio.NewReaderSize(os.Stdin, 10000)
```

P.S.
Go is open source, so you can learn a lot just from looking inside internals.

Comment: Yeah, I know the size of the buffer can be changed but that's not a very nice solution.

Comment: It's very good solution. You must use limits every time. You don't have infinity resources. Just set it to reasonable size for you. It's a best practice.

Comment: Also, just tried this solution, changing the size of the buffer, and it still truncated the input. At this point I'm thinking the problem isn't to do with the buffering.

Comment: What is a system that you try to run your code on it? There exists some  systems that its stdin size is defined by kernel and its size are 4k like the page size. So, if it doesn't work with increased buffer size in go, try to find what your kernel's stdin buffer is.

Comment: Arch Linux. I've heard that running the system in raw mode would fix this issue, but I can't find a pure-go solution other than either use termbox and implement getch-type behaviour, or use ssh/terminal (didn't work as far as I tested.