# Cannot cypher more than 4096 bytes using AES encryption in go

Tags: arrays, go, encryption, aes

I am building a program which has some large strings I want to be cyphered (so they cannot just be read from the binary). To do so, I am trying to save the strings cyphered with AES encryption and decypher them in runtime.

I have been looking into how to do this and managed to cypher some small texts, but it seems my cypher program **cannot cypher more than 4096 bytes** of text, as it cuts the text when it reaches this length. I was wondering if there was some way to increment the buffer the AES Go module uses or another way around this problem.

This is the code I am using to cypher the strings

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "strings"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "encoding/base64"
)

func encrypt(text, keyText string) string {
    key := []byte(keyText)
    plaintext := []byte(text)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    stream := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    stream.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)

    return base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Encryption Program v1.0.0 ~ by: Sam Sepiol")
    
    fmt.Print("[Encryption Key (32 bytes)]>>: ")
    in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    plaintextKey, err := in.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        print("Error reading line\n", 9)
    }
    plaintextKey = strings.Replace(plaintextKey, "\n", "", -1) // strip chars from line

    for {
         fmt.Print(">> ")

        in := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        plaintext, err := in.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            print("Error reading line\n", 9)
        }
        plaintext = strings.Replace(plaintext, "\n", "", -1) // strip chars from line

        result := encrypt(plaintext, plaintextKey)
        
        fmt.Printf("\n\n%s\n\n", result)

    }
}
```

Comment: For larger plaintext I would like to see connected streams such as textstream -> utf8encodestream -> encryptstream -> base64stream, so you can just offer it strings piecemeal.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in my environment with a nearly 7000 bytes plaintext. The encryption itself does not seem to be the problem, it also works in the Go Playground for e.g. those 7000-bytes-plaintext: https://go.dev/play/p/fMem7LPUF9D. So it is rather the I/O, see also this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779856/read-large-amount-of-data-from-standard-input).